# Express redirect based off URL

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

I'm using `Express` & `Node.js`.

```
router.get('/:year?/:month?/:day?', function(req, res) {

  var date = moment();
  if (req.params.year && req.params.month && req.params.day) {
    var dateString = req.params.year + " " + req.params.month + " " + req.params.day;
    var tempDate = moment(dateString, "DD MM YYYY");
    if (tempDate.isValid()) {
      date = tempDate;
    }
  }
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.send("Error");
    });
});
```

The above isn't my full code for my route. But I need some pointers. I'm using Moment.js(http://momentjs.com/) to grab the current date, format it and pass it through the url in the `route.get` request.

However, I don't want the user to be able to go to a past date. So if the date has already been and the user tries to navigate too it I want to redirect them back to the current date.

```
.then (function(){
  var pastDate = function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.[pastDate]) {
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {}
  }
})
```

I don't think the the syntax is correct. But not sure if i'm looking on the right lines in how I'd do this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through your code and it looks really inconsisten and I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but you can probably narrow it down to something like this:

```
router.get('/:year?/:month?/:day?', function (req, res) {
  var year = req.params.year;
  var month = req.params.month;
  var day = req.params.day;  

  if (year && month && day) {
    var requestDate = moment(day + ' ' + month + ' ' + year);
    var today = moment();

    if (requestDate.isValid() && !requestDate.isBefore(today)) {
      // All set and valid, do stuff with the request
    } else {
      // Invalid date or the requested date is before today
      // Redirecting to /year/month/day of this day, e.g /2015/04/31
      return res.redirect('/' + today.year() + '/' + today.month() + '/' + today.date());
    }
  }
});
```

Moment has an [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) method that is really handy for these kind of tasks.

You should use a bit more variables in your code so it's easier to work with! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do a less than comparison.

```
var goodDate = function() {
  var now = moment();
  if (this < now) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: misread what your isValid function was doing.  Just check against goodDate().  If it is false, redirect.